# How to add Bit Bucket commit details in email after build complete in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

Currently i am using Jenkins for CI/CD purpose and Email Extension Plugin for sending mail. I need to include commit details and changes in email and send it to default recipient after build completed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply specify `'${SCRIPT,template="groovy-html.template"}'` as the body of the email.

```
emailext (
    mimeType: 'text/html',
    subject: '$BUILD_STATUS: $PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER',
    to: '$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS',
    body: '${SCRIPT,template="groovy-html.template"}'
)
```

This is one of the default email templates that also displays the changelog with color coded build status.

[image]

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGxxL.png]

Comment: Thanks. It worked fine but not getting colour code , i am using Content Type : HTML . Also where can i find these groovy-html.template file, i can't find it in JENKINS_HOME  : /var/lib/jenkins default location

Comment: Try changing the content type to `text/html`. The templates are located in `${JENKINS_HOME}/email-templates`.

Comment: Checked but there is no email-templates folder in ${JENKINS_HOME} directory.Tried text/html content type but not working.

Comment: Could you please post how you are calling the plugin. The file certainly must be under `${JENKINS_HOME}/email-templates`, in your case `/var/lib/jenkins/email-templates`.

Comment: In Post build section i am calling Editable email notification plugin and adding ${SCRIPT,template="groovy-html.template"} in Default Content Section of it .